# Change Imploding and Exploding

Tags: php

This code add ads in the content. I want to change the output.  I added new details. I tried on it but I could not solve the problem.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'ads_paragraphs');
function ads_paragraphs( $content ) {

    $adsbeforeparagraph = array(1,3,5);

    global $post;

     $ad = 'ADS CODE';

    $content_expl = explode("<p>", $content);
    for ($i = 0; $i <count($content_expl); $i++ ) {
        if (in_array($i, $adsbeforeparagraph)){
            $content_expl[$i] = $ad . $content_expl[$i];
            }
    } 

     return implode("<p>", $content_expl);
    }
```

input is here:

```
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
```

output is here:

```
<p>ADS CODEtext text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>ADS CODEtext text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>ADS CODEtext text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
```

I want this output:

```
ADS CODE<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
ADS CODE<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
ADS CODE<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what your code does. Can you include a few inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
       $adsbeforeparagraph = array(1,3,5);

   global $post;

    $ad = 'ADS CODE';
    $content='<p>text text text </p>
                <p>text text text</p>
                <p>text text text </p>
                <p>text text text </p>
                <p>text text text </p>
                <p>text text text </p>';
    $content_expl = explode("<p>", $content);
    for ($i = 1; $i <count($content_expl); $i++ ) {     
        if (in_array($i, $adsbeforeparagraph)){
            $content_expl[$i] ='ADS CODE <p>'.$content_expl[$i].'<p>';
        }
    }
    print_r(implode(" ", $content_expl));
```

Check this , I've checked this. It works...

Comment: The OP stated they want the output to be - ADS CODE<p>text text text</p>

Comment: Now it's okey tim?

Comment: $ad = 'ADS CODE<p>';
//In loop if condition
$content_expl[$i] = $ad . $content_expl[$i]..'</p>'
            }
    return implode(" ", $content_expl);

Comment: I tried again, but the code works incorrectly, not the result I wanted.

Comment: What is the output you are getting

Comment: ADS CODE<p> ADS CODE<p>text text text</p>
 text text text</p>
 ADS CODE<p>text text text</p>
 text text text</p>
 ADS CODE<p>text text text</p>
 text text text</p>

Comment: Only one code is extra..remove the first one..check the code once again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159359/discussion-between-darshan-and-tenah).

Comment: @Tenah You do notice that this answer is creating an output with the p-tag missing on every other line? https://3v4l.org/b0Pov

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's local or online version. This looks better than the previous but you still have spaces at the wrong places. I think that it is because both you and OP start at the wrong end of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

I use in_array to find out if the current line should have Ads before.
Notice I subtracted 1 from your values since normal arrays count from 0.
If you must have 1,3,5 I can fix that.

```
$input= "<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>";

$arr =explode(PHP_EOL, $input);

 $adsbeforeparagraph = array(0,2,4); // subtracted 1 to suit normal array numbering
 $ad = 'ADS CODE';

Foreach($arr as $key => $line){
    If(in_array($key, $adsbeforeparagraph)){ // is this a line that should have Ads?
        Echo $ad . $line . "\n";
    }else{
        Echo $line . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ADS CODE<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
ADS CODE<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
ADS CODE<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
```

https://3v4l.org/8DVua